Creating hour column from HH:MM:SS data in R
I'm trying to create a data column that lists only the hour each observation took place from time data that's formatted as HH:MM:SS in R.
I want to do this so I can group observations in my dataset by the hour they took place.
Example time vector: a <- c(22:00:03, 22:00:05, 22:00:07, 22:00:09)
Desired output: [1] 22 22 22 22
My dataset is very large so creating separate vectors with the observations based on hour feels time-consuming.
I've tried to explore the 'lubridate' function but I'm having trouble finding a solution.
Any help is appreciated!

Please read about how to make a great R reproducible example and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of dput(<your data frame>) into your post or dput(head(<your data frame>)) if you have a large data frame. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data. Also include code you have tried, any relevant errors, and expected output.

You will get more help if you post a reproducible example and expected output.

substr(a, 1, 2)

library(readr) parse_number(a)

library(data.table); hour(as.ITime(a))

library(lubridate) a <- hms(a) hour(a)

If you are using the lubridate package to parse your dates. You can use lubridate::hour to get the hours. Like: x <- lubridate::hms( c("22:00:03", "22:00:05", "22:00:07", "22:00:09")) %>% lubridate::hour()

You could use a regular expression to get the first two digits:
as.numeric(gsub("(^\\d{2}).*", "\\1", a))
# [1] 22 22 22 22

Convert it to POSIXlt and then format it to extract the hour:
as.numeric(format(strptime(a, "%H:%M"), "%H"))
# [1] 22 22 22 22

In lubridate you can convert it using hms(), which will transform a character vector in the format HH:MM to a period object and then extract the hour component:
library(lubridate)

hour(hms(a))
# [1] 22 22 22 22

The dttr2 package has a similar syntax to lubridate for this:
library(dttr2)

dtt_hour(dtt_time(a))
# [1] 22 22 22 22

Split it by : and take the first element:
as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(a, ":", fixed = TRUE), `[[`, 1))
# [1] 22 22 22 22

stringr implemented str_split_i() in package version 1.5.0 that allows you to split and select the element by index:
library(stringr)

as.numeric(str_split_i(a, ":", 1))
# [1] 22 22 22 22

The strex package can make common regular expressions easier to use to extract everything before the first pattern match:
library(strex)

as.numeric(str_before_first(a, ":"))
# [1] 22 22 22 22

Use the package datetime to turn it into a time object, convert it to numeric (which will return seconds) and convert that to hours:
library(datetime)

as.numeric(as.time(a)) / (60 * 60)
# [1] 22 22 22 22


I used the second function using the as.numeric, format, and strptime and that worked great.

Try sub
a <- c("22:00:03", "22:00:05", "22:00:07", "22:00:09")

sub <- as.numeric(sub(":.*", "", a))
## [1] 22 22 22 22

Comparing this to those posted (plus difftime and chron solutions) in order of median time (fastest first), substr was fastest but substr and gsub solutions assume zero filled hour whereas the others don't so of the solutions which solve the general problem that allows for non-zero filled hour sub is the fastest. The fastest 3 general solutions are all base solutions.  The chron and dttr2 solutions seem the most readable or possibly lubridate depending on whether you think time or hms is more readable.
library(lubridate)
library(dttr2)
library(strex)
library(datetime)
library(chron)
library(microbenchmark)

a <- c("22:00:03", "22:00:05", "22:00:07", "22:00:09")

microbenchmark(
  substr = substr(a, 1, 2), # assumes 0-filled hour
  sub = as.numeric(sub(":.*", "", a)), 
  gsub = as.numeric(gsub("(^\\d{2}).*", "\\1", a)), # assumes 0-filled hour
  strsplit = as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(a, ":", fixed = TRUE), `[[`, 1)),
  POSIXlt = as.numeric(format(strptime(a, "%H:%M"), "%H")),
  datetime = as.numeric(as.time(a)) / (60 * 60),
  difftime = as.integer(as.difftime(a), unit = "hour"),
  chron = chron::hours(times(a)),
  strex = as.numeric(str_before_first(a, ":")),
  lubridate = lubridate::hour(hms(a)),
  dttr2 = dtt_hour(dtt_time(a))
)

giving
Unit: microseconds
      expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
    substr    4.4    7.90    8.957    8.90   10.20    19.4   100
       sub   37.5   45.90   53.228   51.40   60.60    91.9   100
      gsub   56.1   71.35   81.032   78.95   90.60   147.5   100
  strsplit   73.4   89.70   98.007  100.80  103.30   150.6   100
   POSIXlt  133.8  148.80  164.063  165.20  177.00   214.9   100
  datetime  193.1  219.90  245.828  233.05  258.50   433.0   100
  difftime  290.9  325.35  357.287  354.55  374.75   613.5   100
     chron  291.1  320.50  357.119  367.05  379.15   573.7   100
     strex  742.2  815.10  916.158  921.70  953.60  1602.0   100
 lubridate 1007.9 1100.60 1262.641 1176.25 1225.85  7782.4   100
     dttr2 8321.5 8574.90 8841.866 8724.10 8897.80 13899.2   100


You may want to add as.numeric(substr(a, 1, 2)), it's faster by an order of magnitude. Assuming hours have two digits as they usually should have of course.

Have added but that assumes a zero filled hour whereas the others (except gsub) don't so sub is still the fastest of the general solutions.
